# How do I detect the left eye or right eye using haar_cascade with openCV

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

```
import cv2
import matplotlib as plt

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  
while(True):
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\TOI\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    face = face_detector.detectMultiScale(frame, scaleFactor=1.15,minNeighbors=5,minSize=(34,35), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
    face = face_detector.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in face:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    right_eye_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\TOI\haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml')
    right_eye = right_eye_detector.detectMultiScale(frame, scaleFactor=1.15,minNeighbors=5,minSize=(34,35), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
    right_eye = right_eye_detector.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in right_eye:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    
    left_eye_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\TOI\haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml')
    left_eye = right_eye_detector.detectMultiScale(frame, scaleFactor=1.15,minNeighbors=5,minSize=(34,35), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
    left_eye = right_eye_detector.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in left_eye:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)


    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Do I have to split the video into 2? Is there a difference between the righteye and lefteye cascade files? Because when I run it both eyes get detected. Also, how do I make it that the classifier only detect one item?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57697297/3595907)